# SQL Server 2019 Express I can't connect

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, express, tedious

I can't connect to SQL Server with mssql library for my express project. I can connect with VS Code and SQL Server Management Studio

```
var express = require('express');
var app =
 express();
const sql = require('mssql')  
var config = {
    user: 'eren',
    password: 'PAssPoxx1.',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'AIRPLANE',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true}  
};  
const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)  
.connect()  
.then(pool => {  
console.log('Connected to MSSQL')  
return pool  
})  
.catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err)) 


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
// Configuration object for your database

// connect to the database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    console.log("x")
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();
       
    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from User', function (err, recordset) {
        
        if (err) console.log(err)
        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);
        
    });
});
});
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

My errors says:

> Database Connection Failed! Bad Config:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at Connection. (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:68:17)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:12)
> at C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21
> at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
> at Socket.onError (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) {
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at ConnectionError (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1290:56)
> at C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1116:21
> at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
> at Socket.onError (C:\Users\Anıl Eren\Downloads\database-api\node_modules\mssql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
> code: 'ESOCKET'
> }
> }

EDIT:
TCP/IP enabled
Port 1433

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {
    user: 'eren',
    password: 'PAssPoxx1.',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'AIRPLANE',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        enableArithAbort: true}  
};
```

Is your sqlserver instance named mssqlserver? if not you have to specify the instance name 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' in most cases.

Comment: I check instance name it is MSSQLSERVER

Comment: I added the options 
instanceName: "MSSQLSERVER" but now connection timeout

Comment: I disabled my windows firewall on a local server and it all started to work just fine.